# Matrices operation

Tags: matrices

I have two matrices: $A\in\Re^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\Re^{n\times n}$ furthermore $x\in\Re^{n}$ and $y\in\Re^{n}$, I have the following equality:

$$Ax=By$$

1) Can I write it like this?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & -B
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}=0_v$$
where $0_v$ is the vector with all entries equal to zero.

2) Is it correct to state that the solution the problem in point 1) are:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix} \mid \begin{bmatrix}
x
\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix} \in ker(\begin{bmatrix}
A & -B
\end{bmatrix})$$

Thank you

Comment: Is $\Re$ the set of real numbers ($\mathbb R$) ?

Comment: yes it is the set of real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Technically, no, but it's ok with $\begin{bmatrix}A&-B\end{bmatrix}$ instead
2. Yes.

Comment: @iacopo For 2) you may want to change the matrix in your kernel according to 1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer i edit the question